# How to navigate between the named commit and unnamed commit in git

Tags: git

I am working on a file say x and added a some new lines of code, which I don't want to commit yet. Mean while I wanted to look at some previous commit, which I can do by `git checkout bla`. But how do I go back to the not commited original x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are on `master` branch (but it would work for any branch you're on):

- first stash your changes: `git stash`
- then go to the previous commit you are interested in, e.g.: `git checkout 0c80e02`
- look at it
- go back to master: `git checkout master`
- restore stashed changes: `git stash pop`

If you tried to do without `stash`, you'd get a message saying that your local changes would be overwritten by the `checkout`.

For more information see the documentation: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing

Answer (score 1):

You can hide your changes with [git stash](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) and go to needed commit

```
git stash
git checkout COMMIT1_HASH
```

then you can return to latest commit and unstash

```
git checkout COMMIT2_HASH
git stash apply
```

Comment: but I have not made a commit in latest right! remember, I don't want to commit the recent changes just yet. So how commit2_hash comes in to the picture?

Comment: It's the latest commit. All uncommited changes will be in stash. You should checkout to latest commit just to apply this changes if you want

Comment: Thanks, got it clarified